# How to remove highlighting color?

Tags: macros, highlighting

How would you remove highlighting color from LaTeX with one command? I have used the `soul` package with its command `\hl`.

Comment: `\renewcommand\hl[1]{#1}` ?

Comment: Or `\AtBeginDocument{\let\hl\relax}`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi -- I'd say `\let\hl\@gobble` is better; it gets rid of the superflous group.

Comment: @Ruben are you sure you want to remove the text as well as the colour:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- XD! Sure, no text, no highlighting: problem solved... I meant `\@firstofone` and not `\@gobble`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\hl\@firstofone}
\makeatother
```

in the preamble to disarm the `\hl` command (or any other one). In principle you could also `\let` to `\relax` as @LaRiFaRi proposed, but this would leave your text inside a superfluous group, i.e. `{...}`.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, but I am unable to follow your suggestion. Where to put this 
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\hl\@firstofone}
\makeatother

Comment: @Sohail -- You're welcome! Just put it anywhere in the preamble, which means in between `\documentclass...` and `\begin{document}.`

Comment: Works like a charm!